# Google Sheets URL with "&rm=minimal" works perfectly -- but defeats script

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When you append any Google Sheet URL with "&rm=minimal" (omitting the double quotes) - the Sheet will very nicely render in any browser without the Tool Bar or Formula bar.

This frees up a lot of space and is great for applications where you don't want/need those screen elements - and you just want users to see the sheet.

However, I have a couple of onOpen commands in my associated script which does not run in a sheet whose URL has been modified with "&rm=minimal"

```
  function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('test!A1').clearContent(); 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('test!A15').clearContent();
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening -- and if there is a workaround?

Comment: Script editor> view > executions. Any failure logs?

Comment: I couldn't find anything about this yet, but I noticed that onEdit() functions do work with this parameter. I think the onOpen trigger has something to do with the menus loading first.

Comment: Thank you Jescannellas.  Your observation provided me with the means to develop a workaround.  Although, I do wish there was some code snippet that I could run at the top of my script to 'satisfy' and fool Google Scripts into making  onOpen commands work when the GUI is minimized.

Comment: No failure logs TheMaster.  But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this is to add another iframe along with the original in html:

```html
<iframe 
  src="<url to the spreadsheet without the ?rm=minimal query>"
  style="visibility:hidden; position: absolute;"
>
</iframe>
```

Using Google Documents iframes in Web Applications have a lot of caveats, another one is that it resets scroll to top by each page refresh for example.